# Generalised Integral $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^n}{\sin ^n x} \ \mathrm{d}x, \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}^+.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I have this integral,  $$I_n=\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^n}{\sin ^n x} \ \mathrm{d}x, \qquad n\in \mathbb{Z}^+.$$
We have the results
$$
\begin{align}
I_1 & = 2C, \\
I_2 &= \pi\log 2, \\
I_4 & = -\frac{\pi^3}{12} + 2\pi\log 2 + \frac{\pi^3}{3}\log 2-\frac{3\pi}{2}\zeta(3),
\end{align} 
$$
where $C$ is Catalan's constant. Can we prove any of these results, or make any progress on $I_3$, or the general case?

Comment: I think your best chance is a recurrence relationship of $I(n)$ in terms of $I(n-2)$ and/or $I(n-1)$.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large I_{4}}$ must be $\displaystyle{\large\color{#c00000}{-\,{\pi^{3} \over 12}} + 2\pi\ln\left(2\right) + {\pi^{3} \over 3}\,\ln\left(2\right) - {3\pi \over 2}\,\zeta\left(3\right)}$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Integrating by parts, we have
$$
\int \frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x} \, dx= -x^2 \cot x +\int 2x \cot x \, dx\\=
-x^2 \cot x + 2x \ln \sin x - \int 2 \ln \sin x \, dx
$$
Evaluating this between $0$ and $\pi/2$, we find that the boundary terms vanish (by taking the appropriate limits), so we are left with the well-known integral
$$
-2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln \sin x \, dx
=\pi \ln 2
$$

Edit: I have found a way to do $I_1$. Integrating by parts,
$$
\int \frac{x}{\sin x} \, dx= x \ln \tan \frac{x}{2} - \int \ln \tan \frac{x}{2} \, dx
$$
Evaluating between $0$ and $\pi/2$ yields
$$
I_1 = -2 \int_0^{\pi/4} \ln \tan x \, dx\\
= -2 \int_{-\infty}^{0} x \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}} \, dx\\
= 2 \sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-(2k+1)x} \, dx \\
= 2 \sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2} \\
= 2C
$$
as was to be proved.

Answer (score 18):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:

> $$\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\bigg(\frac{x}{\sin x}\bigg)^ndx=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}2^{n-j}\begin{bmatrix}n\\j+1\end{bmatrix}\sum\limits_{v=0}^j\binom{j}{v}(-n)^{j-v+1}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{\big\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\big\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^l\Big(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\Big)^{n-2l+1}}{(n-2l+1)!}f_n(2l-v),$$

with the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) $\begin{bmatrix}n\\k\end{bmatrix}$ defined by $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\begin{bmatrix}n\\k\end{bmatrix}x^k:=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k),$

with $f_{2m-1}(s):=(-1)^{m-1}\beta(s),$ where $\beta(s)$ := [Dirichlet $\beta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function),

and $f_{2m}(s):=(-1)^{m-1}2^{-s}\eta(s),$ where $\eta(s)$ := [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function),

for $m\in\mathbb{N}$, with the analytical extensions $(s\in\mathbb{C})$

$B_n(x)$ are here the Bernoulli Polynomials.

> $$\begin{align}
> \beta(1-s)&=\bigg(\dfrac{2}{\pi}\bigg)^s\sin\bigg(\dfrac{\pi s}{2}\bigg)~\Gamma(s)~\beta(s)
> \\\\
> \eta(1-s)&=\dfrac{2^s-1}{1-2^{s-1}}~\pi^{-s}\cos\bigg(\dfrac{\pi s}{2}\bigg)~\Gamma(s)~\eta(s)
> \end{align}$$

and with the simplifications $(k\in\mathbb{N}_0)$

> $$\begin{align}
> \beta(-2k-1)~&=~0
> \\\\
> \beta(-2k)~&=~-\frac{2^{4k+1}}{2k+1}~B_{2k+1}\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)
> \\\\
> \beta(2k+1)~&=~(-1)^{k-1}~\frac{(2\pi)^{2k+1}}{2(2k+1)!}~B_{2k+1}\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)
> \\\\
> \eta(1-k)~&=~\frac{2^k-1}{k}~B_k
> \\\\
> \eta(2k)~&=~(-1)^{k-1}~\frac{2^{2k-1}-1}{(2k)!}~B_{2k}~\pi^{2k}
> \\\\
> \eta(2k+1)~&=~\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\bigg)\zeta(2k+1)
> \end{align}$$

---

Examples include:

> $$\begin{align}
> \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\bigg(\frac{x}{\sin x}\bigg)^1dx~&=~2\beta(2)\approx1.83
> \\\\
> \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\bigg(\frac{x}{\sin x}\bigg)^2dx~&=~\pi\ln2\approx2.178
> \\\\
> \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\bigg(\frac{x}{\sin x}\bigg)^3dx~&=~-6\beta(4)+\bigg(\frac{3}{4}\pi^2+6\bigg)\beta(2)-\frac{3}{8}\pi^2\approx2.64
> \\\\
> \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\bigg(\frac{x}{\sin x}\bigg)^4dx~&=~-\frac{3}{2}\pi\zeta(3)+\bigg(\frac{\pi^3}{3}+2\pi\bigg)\ln2-\frac{\pi^3}{12}\approx3.27
> \\\\
> \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\bigg(\frac{x}{\sin x}\bigg)^5dx~&=~90\beta(6)-\bigg(\frac{45}{4}\pi^2+100\bigg)\beta(4)+\bigg(\frac{45}{192}\pi^4+\frac{25}{4}\pi^2+10\bigg)\beta(2)-
> \\
> &-\bigg(\frac{55}{384}\pi^4+\frac{5}{8}\pi^2\bigg)\approx4.135
> \end{align}$$

Comment: Fantastic and underrated answer.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen : Very kind of you, thanks ! (But: for a better rating I should explain more of course ... :-) )

Comment: How do we know your initial claim?

Comment: @clathratus : I have to explain more, of course, but it's a lot, I need too much time for it. And my answer came 2 years too late. Therefore I wrote only the answer for interested people, not the whole explanation. If you like to do busywork, you should start with $\sin x = (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/(i2)$, the rest comes on its own. By the way: You can also look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933377/closed-form-of-int-0-infty-frac-arctanxxndx?noredirect=1&lq=1) for similar ideas.

Answer (score 17):

Integrating by parts 3 times,

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \frac{x^{4}}{\sin^{4} x} \ dx &= - \frac{x^{4}}{3} \cot(x) \left(\csc^{2} (x) +2 \right) \Bigg|^{\pi/2}_{0} + \frac{4}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot (x) \left(\csc^{2} (x) +2 \right) \ dx \\ &= \frac{4}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot (x) \left(\csc^{2} (x) +2 \right) \ dx \\ &= \frac{8}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot(x) \ dx + \frac{4}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot(x) \csc^{2}(x) \ dx \\ &= \frac{8}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot(x) \ dx - \frac{2}{3}x^{3} \cot^{2}(x) \Bigg|^{\pi/2}_{0} + 2 \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{2} \cot^{2}(x) \ dx \\ &= \frac{8}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot(x) \ dx + 2 \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{2} \cot^{2} (x) \ dx \\ &= \frac{8}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot(x) \ dx -2x^{2} \Big( x + \cot(x) \Big) \Bigg|^{\pi/2}_{0} +4 \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x\Big(x+ \cot(x) \Big) \ dx \\ &= \frac{8}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot(x) \ dx - \frac{\pi^{3}}{4} + 4 \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{2} \ dx + 4 \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x \cot(x) \ dx \\ &= \frac{8}{3} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot(x) \ dx - \frac{\pi^{3}}{12} + 4 \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x \cot(x) \ dx . \end{align}$$

In general, $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \cot(x) \ dx = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \sin (2nx) \ dx .$$

[See here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517080/equivalence-of-integral-and-sum)

So $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \cot(x) \ dx &= 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x^{3} \sin (2nx) \ dx \\ &= 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1} \pi^{3}}{16n} - \frac{(-1)^{n-1} 3\pi}{8n^{3}} \right) \\ &= \frac{\pi^{3}}{8} \ln (2) - \frac{3 \pi}{4} \eta(3) \\ &= \frac{\pi^{3}}{8} \ln (2) - \frac{9 \pi }{16} \zeta(3). \end{align}$$

And

$$ \begin{align} \int^{\pi /2}_{0} x \cot(x) \ dx &= 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x \sin(2nx) \ dx \\ &=  -\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \\ &= \frac{\pi \ln 2}{2} . \end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \frac{x^{4}}{\sin^{4} x} \ dx &= \frac{8}{3} \left( \frac{\pi^{3}}{8} \ln (2) - \frac{9 \pi }{16} \zeta(3) \right) - \frac{\pi^{3}}{12} + 4 \left(\frac{\pi \ln 2}{2} \right) \\ &= - \frac{\pi^{3}}{12} + 2 \pi \ln(2) + \frac{\pi^{3}}{3} \ln (2) - \frac{3 \pi}{2} \zeta(3) . \end{align}$$

Answer (score 8):

Using a CAS, I obtained $$I_3=\frac{1}{256} \left(192 \left(8+\pi ^2\right) C-96 \pi ^2-\psi
   ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)+\psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$$  $$I_6=\frac{1}{320} \pi  \left(40 \pi ^2 (-12 \zeta (3)-1+20 \log (2))+240 (15 (\zeta
   (5)-\zeta (3))+\log (16))+\pi ^4 (32 \log (2)-11)\right)$$

Comment: Are you will to share the name of the CAS? My old Maple give solutions only in terms of $\mathrm{polylog}(n,\pm i)$ and Wolfram Alpha shows only numerical values?

Comment: It is a modiied version of Maxima. I must say that I got a lot of trouble with $I_5$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : The maxima which I've installed (v5.24.0) can't integrate even when n=1. Is that modified version available online?

Comment: @gar. No, it is a version we have modified in my research team  many years ago precisely for integration of very nasty functions we worked on at that time. If life is not too short, it is part of my plans to clean it up and propose it to whoever could be interested.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : Oh, I see. That would be a great thing to do! Thanks for your time and work.

Comment: Any chance life has allowed you to go public with your software package? As someone who works with integrals pretty constantly (generally recreationally) I would love to see a package that could produce these results be available

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen. Be sure that, at the present time, this software is a mess and not user-friendly at all. If I had time (take into account my age !) and was in better conditions (almost blind !), I would be pleased to clean it and make it available. It is the result of a lot of work in my research group. Meanwhile, if you have anything you would like me to try, feel free to contact me (my e-mail address is in my profile). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s try the third one, $$
\begin{aligned}
I_3 & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^3}{\sin ^3 x} d x\\&=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^3}{\sin x} d(\cot x) \\
& =-\left[\frac{x^3}{\sin x} \cot x\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{3 x^2 \sin x-x^3 \cos x}{\sin ^2 x} \cot x d x \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(3 x^2 \cot x \csc x-\frac{x^3 \cos ^2 x}{\sin ^3 x}\right) d x \\
& =3 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^2 d(-\csc x)-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^3\left(1-\sin ^2 x\right)}{\sin ^3 x} d x \\
& =3\left[-x^2 \csc x\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} +6 I_1-I_3+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^3}{\sin x} d x
\end{aligned}
$$

Rearranging gives$$
I_3=-\frac{3 \pi^2}{8}+6G+ \frac{1}{2}  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^3}{\sin x} d x
$$
For the last integral, we need Euler’s identity $e^{xi}=\cos x+i\sin x$ to transform it into
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^3}{\sin x} d x&=2 i \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^3}{e^{x i}-e^{-x i}} d x \\
= & 2 i \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^3 e^{-x i}}{1-e^{-2 x i}} d x \\
= & 2 i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^3 e^{-(2 n+1) x i} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating by parts thrice on the last integral yields
$$
\begin{aligned}&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^3 e^{-(2 n+1) x i} d x \\
=&\frac{(-1)^n}{8(2 n+1)^4}[\pi(2 n+1)\left[-24+\pi(2 n+1)(2 \pi n+\pi-6 i)]+48(-1)^n+48 i \right]\end{aligned}
$$

Plugging back gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^3}{\sin x} d x & =\frac{3 \pi^2}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^2}-12 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^4} \\
& =\frac{3 \pi^2}{2} G-12\beta(4)\\
\end{aligned}$$

where $G$ is the Catalan’s constant and $\beta(.)$ is the [Dirichlet_beta_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

Hence we may conclude that
$$
\boxed{I_3=-\frac{3 \pi^2}{8}+\frac{3\left(8+\pi^2\right) G}{4}-\beta(4)}$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, we can deal with the integral

$$
I(m,n)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^m}{\sin^n x} d x
$$
by establishing a reduction formula via integration by parts.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I(m, n)=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^m}{\sin ^n x} d x  -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^m \csc ^{n-2} x d(\cot x)\\=& m \int_0^\pi \frac{x^{m-1} \cos x}{\sin ^{n-1} x} d x-(n-2) \int_0^\pi x^m \csc ^{n-2} x\left(\csc ^2 x-1\right) d x\\=& -\frac{m}{n-2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^{m-1} d\left(\frac{1}{\sin ^{n-2} x}\right)-(n-2) I(m, n)+(n-2) I(m, n-2)
\end{aligned}
$$

Rearranging and simplifying yields

$$
\boxed{I(m, n)=-\frac{m \pi^{m-1}}{(n-1)(n-2) 2^{m-1}}+\frac{m(m-1)}{(n-1)(n-2)} I(m-2, n-2)+ \frac{n-2}{n-1} I(m, n-2)}
$$
where $m\ge n\ge 3$.  Applying the formula repeatedly, we can find $I(m,n) $ with two initial integrals.

For odd integer $n$, we need to evaluate

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^m}{\sin x} d x $$
which was already solved in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4167610/732917) which states that
\begin{align}
 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^m}{\sin x} d x =\>(2-2^{-m})m!\zeta(m+1)\Re(i^m)
- \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{m+1}2]} (\frac{\pi}2)^{m+1-2k}\>\frac{2(-1)^k m!}{(m+1-2k)!} \>\beta(2k)
\end{align}
For example,
$$
\begin{aligned}I(1,1)&=  -\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^0 2(-1) \beta(2) = 2 G
\\I(3,1)&=-\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4} \cdot \frac{-12}{2} \beta(2)+12 \beta(4)\right) =\frac{3 \pi^2}{2} G-12 \beta(4)
\\I(5,1)&=\frac{5 \pi^4}{8} G-30 \pi^2 \beta(4)+240 \beta(6)\end{aligned}
$$
Coming back to our integral,
$$
I(3,3)=-\frac{3 \pi^2}{8}+3 I(1,1)+\frac{1}{2} I(3,1)= -\frac{3 \pi^2}{8}+\frac{3\left(8+\pi^2\right) }{4}G-6\beta(4)
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}I(5,3)&=-\frac{5 \pi^4}{8}+10 I(3,1)+I(5,1)\\&= 
 \frac{5 \pi^4}{32}+\left(15 \pi^2+\frac{5 \pi^4}{16}\right) G-\left(120+15 \pi^2\right) \beta(4) +120 \beta(6)\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
I(5,5)& = -\frac{5 \pi^4}{192}+\frac{5}{3} I(3,3)+\frac{3}{4} I(5,3)\\&=-\frac{5 \pi^4}{192}+\frac{5}{3}\left(-\frac{3 \pi^2}{8}+\frac{3\left(8+\pi^4\right)}{4} G-6 \beta(4)\right)\\ \quad   &+\frac{3}{4}\left[ 
 \frac{5 \pi^4}{32}+\left(15 \pi^2+\frac{5 \pi^4}{16}\right) G-\left(120+15 \pi^2\right) \beta(4) +120 \beta(6) \right]\\&=
- \frac{5 \pi^2}{8}-\frac{35 \pi^4}{384}+\left(10+\frac{45 \pi^2}{4}+\frac{35 \pi^4}{64}\right) G -\left(100+ \frac{45\pi^2}{4}\right) \beta(4)+90 \beta(6)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

For even integers $n$, we need to evaluate
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^m}{\sin^2 x} d x , $$
which is difficult to tackle.