# Evaluate $\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}} \log(1+\cos x)\, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Find the value of $\displaystyle \int_0^{{\pi}/{2}} \log(1+\cos x)\ dx$

I tried to put $1+ \cos x = 2 \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} $, but I am unable to proceed further.
I think the following integral can be helpful:
 $\displaystyle \int_0^{{\pi}/{2}} \log(\cos x)\ dx =-\frac{\pi}{2} \log2 $.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)
$$
t=\tan\frac x2\qquad;\qquad\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\qquad;\qquad dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}\ dt
$$
we obtain
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(1+\cos x)\ dx&=2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln2}{1+t^2}\ dt}_{\color{blue}{\text{set}\ t=\tan\theta}}-2\color{red}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\ dt}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2-2\color{red}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\ dt}.\tag1
\end{align}
Consider
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\ dt&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\ dt+\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\ dt}_{\large\color{blue}{t\ \mapsto\ \frac1t}}\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\ dt-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\ dt\\
\color{red}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\ dt}&=\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\ dt}_{\color{blue}{\text{set}\ t=\tan\theta}}+\int_0^1\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\ dt\\
&=-\underbrace{\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln\cos\theta\ d\theta}_{\color{blue}{\Large\text{*}}}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\underbrace{\int_0^1 t^{2k}\ln t\ dt}_{\color{blue}{\Large\text{**}}}\\
&=\frac\pi2\ln2-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^2}\\
&=\frac\pi2\ln2-\text{G},\tag2
\end{align}
where $\text{G}$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

[$(*)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690705/123277) can be proven by using the symmetry of $\ln\cos\theta$ and $\ln\sin\theta$ in the interval $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$ and $(**)$ can be proven by using formula
[$$
\int_0^1 x^\alpha \ln^n x\ dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(\alpha+1)^{n+1}}, \qquad\text{for }\  n=0,1,2,\ldots
$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/877844/123277)
Thus, plugging in $(2)$ to $(1)$ yields
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(1+\cos x)\ dx
=\large\color{blue}{2\text{G}-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2}.
\end{align}

Comment: $$
{\rm G} = -\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\left(\,t\,\right) \over 1 + t^{2}}\,{\rm d}t
$$
[from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant#Integral_identities).

Comment: @FelixMarin Thanks Felix. I just wanna represent $G$ in form of series since it's more familiar than its integral representation.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a formula I find quite useful:
$$
\begin{align}
\log(1+\cos(x))
&=\log\left(\frac{e^{ix}+2+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=2\log\left(e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2}\right)-\log(2)\tag{2}\\
&=2\left[ix/2+\log\left(1+e^{-ix}\right)\right]-\log(2)\tag{3}\\
&=2\left[-ix/2+\log\left(1+e^{ix}\right)\right]-\log(2)\tag{4}\\
&=\log\left(1+e^{ix}\right)+\log\left(1+e^{-ix}\right)-\log(2)\tag{5}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{e^{ikx}}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{k}-\log(2)\tag{6}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}-\log(2)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$
$(2)$: pull out the $\log(2)$ and use $\left(e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2}\right)^2=e^{ix}+2+e^{-ix}$
$(3)$: pull $e^{ix/2}$ out of $\log\left(e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2}\right)$ in $(2)$
$(4)$: pull $e^{-ix/2}$ out of $\log\left(e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2}\right)$ in $(2)$
$(5)$: average $(3)$ and $(4)$
$(6)$: use the power series for $\log(1+x)$
$(7)$: $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$

---

Apply the formula above to the integral in the question:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(1+\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac\pi2\log(2)\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}\sin(k\pi/2)-\frac\pi2\log(2)\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}-\frac\pi2\log(2)\\
&=2\mathrm{G}-\frac\pi2\log(2)\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
where $\mathrm{G}$ is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: Nice solution!!

Answer (score 4):

hint:
$$\int\ln[1+\cos(x)]dx=\int\ln\left[2\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]dx\\=\int\ln(2)dx+\int\ln\left[\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]dx\\=\ln(2)\int dx+2\int\ln\left[\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]dx\\=\ln(2)\int dx+4\int\ln\cos(t)dt\bigg|_{t=x/2}$$
then you can use your helpful integration to have the result.

Comment: @Travis yes, you are right. But I find another problem, the last term $\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln\cos(t)dt$ is not same as the proposed formula. I havn't find good solution. My answer should be improved.

Comment: The simplest method seems to be to use an identity that I've used quite a bit: $$\log(1+\cos(x))=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}-\log(2)$$ Integrating this and knowing [Catalan's Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) finishes things up. I use these in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\color{red}{\int^{\pi/2}_0\log(1+\cos{x}){\rm d}x}
&=\int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{x\sin{x}}{1+\cos{x}}{\rm d}x\tag1\\
&=\int^{\pi/2}_0 x\tan{\frac{x}{2}} \ {\rm d}x\tag2\\
&=4\int^{\pi/4}_0x\tan{x} \ {\rm d}x\tag3\\
&=8\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n-1}\int^{\pi/4}_0x\sin(2nx) \ {\rm d}x\tag4\\
&=2\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{n^2}-\pi\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{n}\\
&=2\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right)}{(2n+1)^2}-\color{grey}{2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\sin\left(n\pi\right)}{4n^2}}\\
&-\color{grey}{\pi\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right)}{2n+1}}+\pi\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\cos\left(n\pi\right)}{2n}\tag5\\
&=2\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\tag6\\
&\large{\color{red}{=2G-\frac{\pi}{2}\log{2}}}\tag7\\
\end{align}
**Explanation:** 
$(1)$: [Integrate by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) 
$(2)$: Trigonometric identities 
$(3)$: Substitute $x\mapsto \frac{x}{2}$ 
$(4)$: Use the [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) of $\tan{x}$ 
$(5)$: Split the sum into odd and even terms. It is obvious that the grey sums $=0$ 
$(6)$: $\sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right)=\cos{n\pi}=(-1)^n$ for integer $n$. This can be verified easily. 
$(7)$: The first sum is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant). The second is $-\log(1+1)$. (Taylor's series)

Comment: @Travis I added in the explanation for each step.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is especially nice.

Comment: This solution is very nice indeed!

Answer (score 3):

Let's try your way. Put $1+\cos x=2\cos^2\frac x2$ and use substitution $\frac x2\mapsto x$, we get
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}} \log(1+\cos x)\ dx=\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}} \log2\ dx +4\int_0^{{\pi}/{4}} \log \cos x\ dx
\end{equation}
The first integral is a piece of cake and the second integral has been evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/199094/346183). The final result is
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}} \log(1+\cos x)\ dx=\frac{\pi}{2} \log2 +4\left(\frac C2-\frac{\pi}{4} \log2\right)=2C-\frac{\pi}{2} \log2
\end{equation}