# How to use contour method with $\int_0^{\pi} \tan (x) \log \left(\cos ^2(x)\right) dx =0$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

To solve $\int \tan (x) \log \left(\cos ^2(x)\right)  dx$ one may use the identity:

$\int f'(x)[f(x)]^n dx = \frac{[f(x)]^{n+1}}{n+1}\, n\neq-1$ resulting in $-\frac{1}{4} \log ^2\left(\cos ^2(z)\right)$

Specifically I would like to use the contour method for principle value $\int_0^{\pi} \tan (x) \log \left(\cos ^2(x)\right) dx =0$

I would like to also find if possible the more difficult principle value $\int_0^{\frac{2\pi}{3}} \tan (x) \log \left(\cos ^2(x)\right) dx =-\frac{1}{4} \log ^2(4)$

I am trying to use contour integration however there is discontinuity.

The first steps I tried was to find the residues and work out a suitable contour.

I would be grateful if these steps could be shown as in this similar question answered by @dustin [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1122146/161898), the function is modified to use the contour method. I also note a similar method was shown on page 160-1 of  “Complex Analysis” by Ahlfors, this time using a rectangle.

Comment: Contour integration does not handle indefinite integrals. You should include the bounds in the post, not just in the title

Comment: Contour integration is also quite inappropriate for general bounds. You could maybe do $\int_0^\pi$ here, but $\int_0^{42}$ will be essentially impossible with the contour methods

Comment: @FShrike thank you I will overall the question taking that into account

Comment: The integral diverges.

Comment: @Accelerator Since there's a discontinuity in the integrand at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$,the integral needs to be evaluated as a principal value integral (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyPrincipalValue.html).

Comment: I have updated post to state it's a principal value integral.

Answer (score 1):

Contour integration is completely overkill by the way (nevermind tricky to set up). In the same spirit as the now deleted answer, consider that for $0<\epsilon<\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have: $$\left(\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}+\int_{\pi/2+\epsilon}^{\pi}\right)\tan(x)\log(\cos^2(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\\overset{x\mapsto x-\pi/2}{=}-\left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\epsilon}+\int_{\epsilon}^{\pi/2}\right)\cot(x)\log(\sin^2(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$$

The integrand is odd, and properly integrable over this interval for every such $\epsilon$. The above is then zero, always, so the principal value is zero.