# Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\tanh x}{1+\tan x}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, closed-form

I need the method to evaluate this integral (the closed-form if possible).
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\tanh x}{1+\tan x}\,dx
$$
I used the relationship between $\tan x$ and $\tanh x$ but it didn't work. Any help?

Comment: The numerical value is $1.137333875921470087298597734$.

Comment: If you "used the relationship between $\tan x$ and $\tanh x$", you should include the details in your post.  That will help to inform suitable Answers.

Comment: $$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{{\rm d} x \over 1 + \tan\left(\, x\,\right)}
={\pi \over 4}
$$
So, you can avoid the $1$ in the numerator.

Comment: $\dfrac\pi2$ is a meaningless argument to pass to the $\tanh$ function, so I don't expect the integral to have a closed form.

Comment: @Lucian I don't follow. Why should the particular value of $\tanh$ at $\pi/2$ affect anything here?

Comment: @epimorphic: Speaking from my own experience, $($and it's just a simple heuristic, not a theorem or anything$)$, this kind of definite integrals, whose anti-derivative cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, seem only then to possess a closed form themselves, when the limits of integration are “meaningful” to the integrand. In this case, $\tanh\dfrac\pi2$ is a “meaningless” quantity. $($If we could at least get rid of it, but we cannot: the integrand is as simple as can be$)\ldots$

Comment: Perhaps we might have better luck if the upper limit were $\infty$ instead of $\dfrac\pi2$, but computing the principal value of an integral with quite literally an infinite number of poles looks rather daunting, to say the least.

Comment: @Lucian Is the integral even finite frmo $0$ up to $3\pi/4$ ?

Comment: @Raphael: No. But divergence over $(0,3\pi/4)$ does not necessarily imply the divergence of its principal value over $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: For large $x$ we have that $\tanh(x) \approx 1$ so the integral will be close to that of $2/(1+\tan(x))$. If we integrate from one zero of $\tan(x)$ to the next one we pass through a pole. The principal value will be $\pi$. Therefore, if we look at the P.V. of the original integral from 0 to $\infty$ we get a divergent integral, with or without the 1 in the numerator.

Comment: As Felix Martin said, $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{{\rm d} x \over 1 + \tan\left(\, x\,\right)} ={\pi \over 4}$. So we can divide the numerator of $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\tanh x}{1+\tan x}\,dx$ into $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan x}\,dx$ + $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\tanh x}{1+\tan x}\,dx$. The indefinite integral of the left integral is $\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(\sin x+\cos x)$) which when evaluated is $\frac\pi4$ and see this link for the indefinite integral of the right and then plug away: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20by%20parts%20%28tanh%28x%29%29%2F%281%2Btan%28x%29%29&lk=2

Comment: As usual, it seems the best way to get votes for a question on MSE is to ask for a closed form solution to a difficult integral.

Answer (score 4):

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\tanh(x)}{1+\tan(x)}dx=\frac\pi 4+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tanh(x)}{1+\tan(x)}dx$$

$$I_1=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tanh(x)}{1+\tan(x)}dx$$

---

$$\tanh(x)=\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=1-2\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$
so:
$$I_1=\frac{\pi}{4}-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)}\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}dx$$
$$I_2=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)}\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}dx$$

---

$$\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{-2x}}{1-(-e^{-2x})}=e^{-2x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-2nx}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-2(n+1)x}$$
and so:
$$I_2=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-2(n+1)x}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{-2(n+1)x}}{1+\tan(x)}dx$$
as for this integral its quite messy and I'm not sure what to do from here, It would be easier for $0$ to $\pi/4$ I think. I will say that as $n$ increases the terms get smaller very quickly so an approximation of the first few would be quite accurate if possible.

---

One possible way I have noticed is that:
$$e^{-2.5(n+1)x}\le\frac{e^{-2(n+1)x}}{1+\tan(x)}\le e^{-2.4(n+1)x}$$
so if:
$$J(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-ax}dx=\frac{1-e^{-a\pi/2}}{a}$$
so we have:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1-e^{-2.5(n+1)\pi/2}}{2.5(n+1)}\le I_2\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1-e^{-2.4(n+1)\pi/2}}{2.4(n+1)}$$
and according to wolfram alpha these sums converge and arent too ugly, and we know that:
$$I=\pi/2-2I_2$$
thats the best I can do at the moment I'll take another look sometime. It is also worth noting that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}=\ln(2)$$
and the second part of the sum could be expanded into a double summation

---

Back to add a little to this answer, so far we know:
$$\frac{\ln2}{2.5}+\frac 1 {2.5}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1ne^{-2.5n\pi/2}\le I_2\le \frac{\ln2}{2.4}+\frac 1 {2.4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1ne^{-2.4n\pi/2}$$
we will try and focus on sums of the form:
$$S(\alpha)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\exp(-\alpha n)}{n}=-\ln(e^{-\alpha}(e^\alpha-1))$$
according to wolfram alpha, which we are able to simplify to:
$$S(\alpha)=\alpha-\ln(e^\alpha-1)$$
$$\frac{S(\alpha)}{\alpha}=1-\frac{\ln(e^\alpha-1)}{\alpha}$$