# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln\left(e^{2x} + 1\right)}{1 + \sin2x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Here's my Xmas gift to all of you!
I just encountered a very tough integral.
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln\left(e^{2x} + 1\right)}{1 + \sin2x}\mathrm dx$$

I have tried for a few hours. This task is just daunting.

I've been using by-parts bcause that's the only tool I know how to use in this situation. Please educate me on how this integral can be evaluated.

[image: santa]
Thank you :D

Comment: I am not surprised you are finding this daunting. [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+ln%7Ce%5E%282x%29+%2B+1%7C%2F%281%2Bsin%282x%29%29+dx) thinks that you shouldn't be trying too hard on this. What is the source of the integral?

Comment: Xmas is coming and this is your gift, I suppose ! Where did you find such a monster ? Any bounds ? Why to care about the absolute value in numerator ?

Comment: No need absolute sign here since for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the term $e^x+1\ge1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Yes, it was my gift :D I need the area from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta: Oh, so no closed form. Dang, I'll put in some limits then.

Comment: @Venus: Ok, I've removed it and since it didn't have a closed form, I gave it the limits from the original question. Take a whack at it now.

Comment: @Nick Mathematica yields

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln\left(e^{2x} + 1\right)}{1 + \sin2x}\mathrm dx\approx1.830481056481482\cdots$$

Comment: @Integrator: I knew that but I'm not Mathematica, how do I get there?

Comment: @Nick I'm figuring that out!

Comment: @Integrator. If I don't hear from you meanwhile about the solution, I wish you  very merry Xmas **2015**, **2016**, **2017** (no limit) !

Comment: I think this integral if $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ have closed form

Comment: @Integrator Work faster. Christmas depends upon you!

Comment: @math110 yes the closed form solution is $\infty$ :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+ln%7Ce%5E%282x%29+%2B+1%7C%2F%281%2Bsin%282x%29%29+dx+from+0+to+infinity

Comment: Because we know $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin{kx}}{e^{mx}+1}dx=\dfrac{1}{2k}-\dfrac{\pi}{2m}csc {\dfrac{k\pi}{m}}$$ and $$\dfrac{1}{1+\sin{x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(\sin{x})^n$$

Comment: @Nick Excuse my persistence, but I am still curious about why you need to find this integral.

Comment: @Nick so the integral with these limits has a closed form?

Comment: About trivial stuff, $\log(1+e^{2x})=2x+\log(1+e^{-2x})$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{2x}{1+\sin(2x)}dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Note that integrating by parts yields, $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln{\left(e^{2x}+1\right)}}{1+\sin{(2x)}}\,dx=\ln{2}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1+\tanh{x}}{1+\tan{x}}\,dx$. So the integral posted in this question is directly connected to the integral posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002223/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-frac1-tanh-x1-tan-xdx).

Comment: Where $G$ denotes Catalan's constant, I have found that

$$\mathcal{I} = \log 2 + \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\log\cosh\frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{\log 2}{4}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \right) $$
$$+\frac{\pi}{4}\log 2-\frac{G}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\tanh^2x \log\left(\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right) \; dx,$$

whereon a closed form is unlikely to be found.

Comment: Why insist on closed forms if such beasties are a piece of cake numerically?

Comment: @HandeBruijn: The answer I have with me is a numerical approximation. You're right no-one has yet found a closed for form for this beast. Please post your answer using numerical analysis.

Comment: @DavidH: I found that too, I had given a bounty on it. But alas, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asked for an answer using numerical analysis. Let me first say that even Mathematica and MAPLE do not give exactly the same answers for this integral. MAPLE gives:

```
F(x) := ln(exp(2*x)+1)/(1+sin(2*x));
evalf(int(F(x),x=0..Pi/2),16);
                                              1.830481056481415
```

As compared with the value in the comment by Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ : $1.830481056481482$ .
Then  OK, here is a *very* brute force (and *therefore* a piece of cake) program:

```
program numeric;

function F(x : double) : double;
begin
  F := ln(exp(2*x)+1)/(1+sin(2*x));
end;

function lower(N : integer) : double;
var
  k : integer;
  x,dx,sum : double;
begin
  sum := 0;
  dx := (Pi/2)/N;
  for k := 0 to N-1 do
  begin
    x := (Pi/2)*k/N+dx/2;
  { Midpoint rule }
    sum := sum + F(x)*dx;
  end;
  lower := sum;
end;

function upper(N : integer) : double;
var
  k : integer;
  x1,x2,dx,sum : double;
begin
  sum := 0;
  dx := (Pi/2)/N;
  x2 := 0;
  for k := 1 to N do
  begin
    x1 := x2;
    x2 := (Pi/2)*k/N;
  { Trapezium rule }
    sum := sum + (F(x1)+F(x2))/2*dx;
  end;
  upper := sum;
end;

begin
  Writeln(lower(1000000));
  Writeln(upper(1000000));
end.
```

Output:

```
 1.83048105648054E+0000
 1.83048105648321E+0000
```

It helps to make a little sketch of the function $F(x) = \ln(e^{2x}+1)/(1+\sin(2x))$ :

[image]

Due to this function behaviour, the
[Midpoint rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method)
give a lower bound, while the
[Trapezium rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)
gives an upper bound for the integral. Thus we find with certainty that:
$$
  1.830481056480 <
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln\left(e^{2x} + 1\right)}{1 + \sin2x}\mathrm dx
< 1.830481056484
$$
The results with Mathematica and MAPLE are well within these bounds.

Comment: This might qualify as an answer, But it's not worth any bounty.

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ: Agreed with you about the bounty. So I'd say: keep the upvotes low (I don't care too much). There's an update forthcoming though.

Comment: The promised update has been done.

Comment: Ok, but Nick didn't commented anything about $1.830481056481482$

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ: Sorry, my bad! I'm going to correct it.

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ: This answer will do for now. Christmas $2015$ will possibly see a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a method for estimating the integral $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1+e^{2x})}{1+\sin 2x}dx=-\frac{\ln(1+e^{2x})}{1+\tan x}\big|_{0}^{\pi/2}+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{2e^{2x}}{(1+e^{2x})(1+\tan x)}dx\\=\ln 2+J$$ Now, an estimation of $J$ can be found as below. Note that $\forall x\ge 0,\ e^x/(1+e^x)\le x/4+1/2$. Hence $$J<\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{(x+1)dx}{1+\tan x}=\pi/4+\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{1+\tan x}dx$$ The latter integral is found to be $\approx 0.431066$ from [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%2F2%7D%5Cfrac%7B%28x%29%7D%7B1%2B%5Ctan+x%7Ddx). Hence $I<1.90961$.

For a lower bound note that due to concavity for $x>0,\  e^{2x}/(1+e^{2x})>1/2+(2e^\pi/(1+e^\pi)-1)x/\pi \ \forall x\in [0,\pi/2]$. Hence $$J>\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1+2x(2\dfrac{e^\pi}{1+e^\pi}-1)/\pi}{1+\tan x}dx=\pi/4+2(2\frac{e^\pi}{1+e^\pi}-1)/\pi\times 0.431066$$ Hence $I>1.7302$.

**EDIT** To defend the "purity" of my answer as demanded by Mr.G, I am giving a solution to the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{1+\tan x}dx$. This can be evaluated as below
$$L=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{1+\tan x}dx\\=x(x/2+1/2\ln(\sin x +\cos x))\big|_0^{\pi/2}-1/2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left[x+\ln(\sin x +\cos x)\right]dx\\
=\pi^2/16-\pi/8\ln 2+\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln \sec x dx$$ Now, $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln \sec^2 x dx=x\ln (\sec^2 x)\big|_{0}^{\pi/4}-2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}x\tan x dx$$  Let $J=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}x\tan x dx$ and introduce a new integral $K=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\tan x}dx$. We can then see after some manipulations that $$2J+K/2=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{x\sec^2 x}{\tan x} dx\\=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x}dx\\=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}=:C$$ where $C$ is the [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). We will evaluate $K$ using differentiation under integration trick. Define $$K_a=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan^{-1}(a \tan x)}{\tan x}dx\\\Rightarrow \frac{dK_a}{da}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{(a\tan x)^2+1}\\=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dz}{(1+z^2)(1+a^2z^2)}dz=\frac{\pi}{2(a+1)}\\ \Rightarrow K_a=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(a+1)$$using $K_0=0$. Then $K=K_1=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2$. Hence $$J=C/2-\pi/8\ln 2$$ So, we have $$L=\pi^2/16+\pi/8\ln 2-C/2\approx 0.431066$$

Comment: The integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x/(1 + \tan x)\,\text{d}x$ is not trivial; the integrand has no anti-derivative. How is finding its value numerically any easier than just estimating the original integral numerically?

Comment: @Mr.G this integral has a closed form solution in terms of the [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant), see this [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%2F2%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Ctan+x%7D%7B1%2B%5Ctan+x%7Ddx) output to appreciate this fact.

Comment: I like your approach.

Comment: @Nick: Haven't seen Samrat Mukhopadhyay's closed form somewhere. So what's the big deal here ? Compare $1.7302 < I < 1.90961$ with $1.830481056480 < I < 1.830481056484$ and ask any layman.

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Ok, Ok, don't whine about it. You gave the best answer possible (by current standards) but Samrat's was the answer that I could replicate from the top of my head and show to my girlfriend.

Comment: @Nick: Didn't whine, just wondering why. And didn't know that it's possible to change an accept, once given. Last but not least: I didn't mean to frustrate your freedom of choice.

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Well, Santa doesn't exist either. Sorry to ruin your childhood. (but don't worry, all is still well)

Comment: @Nick: Santa needs it for his sleigh!! Why didn't I notice that graph underneath ..

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay The integral in your link is $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} x \tan x/(1 + \tan x) \,\text{d}x$, which is not the integral you referenced in your answer. The integral in your answer is $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} x/(1 + \tan x) \,\text{d}x$ which just gives $\approx 0.431066$ as you stated (ie. not closed.) Furthermore, Catalan's constant is either defined in terms of an infinite series or an integral, so having it appear in a solution doesn't make it "closed form." I might as well say the original integral has a closed form solution because it's equal to $g$, where $g$ is Mr. G's constant.

Comment: Mr. G if you think about it then $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\tan x /(1+\tan x)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\pi/2-x)/(1+\tan x)dx$ and you know that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}1/(1+\tan x)dx=\pi/4$, so that answers your first complaint. For the second part Catalan's constant is something that is tabulated and can be found in literature where unfortunately Mr. G's constant $g$ is not likely to be found. Besides, I have stated that it is just an approach which shows how we can come up with some bounds and have not claimed to be the best, so it is no big deal.

Comment: @HandeBruijn, I stated in my answer that this is an approach to come up with some bounds and have not claimed them to be the best. My answer is something that involves "mathematics"(which I think your answer lacked), not just software, and that is why I posted it.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: That depends entirely upon your definition of "mathematics". I agree with you that my answer isn't very "smart", if that is what you mean. But, when comparing the digits, it's much more effective. And BTW my software is home-made, not "just" press-a-button software.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Okay, I understand the first part. I do  appreciate that your answer is trying to give some bounds on the integral from "pure" arguments and I respect that. I think my problem is that it's not immediately obvious how $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} x \tan x / (1 + \tan x) \, \text{d}x$ is related to Catalan's constant. WolframAlpha states that the result is $(8 C + \pi(\pi - \log 4))/16$ but unless your answer explicitly shows that it seems to defeat the purpose of trying to have a "pure" argument. If I'm allowed to use WolframAlpha, I might as well just type in the original integral.

Comment: I see that you have updated your answer. In my opinion this is now the best answer and I have upvoted you.

Comment: Thanks Mr. G. Patience has brought me a sweet fruit then :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$u=\ln(e^{2x}+1)\to\:du=\frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}$$
$$dv=\frac{1}{1+\sin(2x)}\:\to v=\int{\frac{1}{1+\sin(2x)}}dx$$ 
To solve for v: 
$$dv*\frac{1-\sin(2x)}{1-\sin(2x)}=\frac{1-\sin(2x)}{1-\sin^2(2x)}=\frac{1-\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(2x)}+\frac{-\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}$$

$$\therefore v=\int{\sec^2(2x)+\frac{-\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}dx}=\frac{\tan(2x)}{2}+=\int{\frac{-\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}dx}+C$$
Using U-sub on $$\int{\frac{-\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}dx}$$:

$$u=\cos(2x);du=-2\sin(2x)dx\\=\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{1}{u^2}du}=-\frac{1}{2u}=-\frac{\sec(2x)}{2}\\\therefore v=\frac{\tan(2x)}{2}+\frac{\sec(2x)}{2}$$

Then the new problem is to solve:

$$\frac{(\tan2x+\sec2x)\ln(e^{2x}+1)}{2}-\frac{2}{2}\int{\frac{e^{2x}(\tan2x+\sec2x)}{e^{2x}+1}}$$

And I've run out of time...

Comment: $dv=\frac{1}{1+\sin 2x}!!??$

Comment: This margin is too narrow to contain the full solution, huh?