# Calculate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x)\log{\sin{(x)}}}{x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Inspired by a question I saw these days, I try to calculate in closed form

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x)\log{\sin{(x)}}}{x}\,dx$$

So far no fruitful idea that is worth sharing. What way would you propose? Note I prefer ways suggested,  not necessarily solutions, but I have nothing against any of the options you prefer.

Comment: *What way would you propose?* - In accordance with the ancient Chinese wisdom of the *Tao Te Ching*, I would propose the way of non-action. :-$)~\dfrac{\sin x}x$ doesn't make any sense on $\bigg(0,\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$; it only makes sense on $(0,\infty)$. So, at best, you might want to try $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}x\cdot\ln\big(\sin^2x\big)~dx$.

Comment: @Lucian Chinese wisdom might be right to a certain extent, but not sure if I wanted to try the integral you proposed.

Comment: After working on this for a while, I only managed to get
$$\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{\sin{x}\ln(\sin{x})}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int^1_0\frac{(x+1)\ln{x}\ln(1+x)}{x^{3/2}\left(\ln^2{x}+\pi^2\right)}dx-\mathrm{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\ln{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's not a closed form, but I hope can be useful. Using $$\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)=-\log\left(2\right)-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\cos\left(2nx\right)}{n}$$
 we have$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{x}=-\log\left(2\right)\textrm{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(2nx\right)}{x}dx.$$
 Now we use the identity $$\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(2nx\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\left(x-2nx\right)+\sin\left(2nx+x\right)\right)$$
 to obtain $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{x}=-\log\left(2\right)\textrm{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\textrm{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(2n+1\right)\right)-\textrm{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(2n-1\right)\right)}{n}.$$
 Now, we have that $$\frac{\textrm{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(2n+1\right)\right)-\textrm{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(2n-1\right)\right)}{n}=O\left(\frac{1}{\pi n^{2}}\right)$$
 at $n\rightarrow\infty$
  so we have the approximation $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\left(x\right)\log\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{x}\simeq-\log\left(2\right)\textrm{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\frac{\zeta\left(2\right)}{2\pi}.$$ Note that numerically the integral is $-1.05585$ and my result is $-1.21193...$

Comment: (+1) per il lavoro che hai fatto. However, it would be very nice to find a closed form for that series.