# I need help calculating a primitive function

Tags: derivatives, indefinite-integrals

Could anybody help me find the primitive function of
$$f(x) = \frac{\log{(1-x)}  \tan^2{(x)}}{1-x\tan^2{(x)}}$$
since I'm not really good at it, and I need help :s

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maple can't find one, and that probably means there isn't one.

Comment: That would explain why my teacher asked me, to crack my brains for a bit :p

Comment: Special case of it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869042/the-closed-form-of-int-0-pi-4-frac-log1-x-tan2x1-x-tan2x-dx