# Is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^{\frac 1n}+\sin x}{\tan x+x^{\frac 1n}} dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1+\sin x}{\tan x+1} dx=1.62..$?

Tags: integration, limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

My question here is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2721739/closed-form-for-the-integral-int-0-pi-2-fracx-sin-x-tan-x-x-dx) question , but my question is to know if the below identity is true :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^{\frac 1n}+\sin x}{\tan x+x^{\frac 1n}} dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1+\sin x}{\tan x+1} dx=1.62...$$ .for The RHS of this identity the value of this integral assumed by [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7Bpi%2F2%7D+%5Cfrac%7B+1%2B(%5Csin+x)%7D%7B%5Ctan+x%2B1%7D+dx) to be $1.62..$ with a closed form.

**Note:** The LHS of this identity it's seems converges for every positive integer $n\geq 1$ over the range $(0,\frac \pi2)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting
$$ 0\le \sin x\le x, \tan x\ge x, x\in[0,\frac\pi2] $$
one has
$$ 0\le\frac{x^{\frac1n}+\sin x}{\tan x+x^{\frac1n}}\le\frac{x^{\frac1n}+ x}{x+x^{\frac1n}}=1$$
which implies
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x^{\frac1n}+\sin x}{\tan x+x^{\frac1n}}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{\frac1n}+\sin x}{\tan x+x^{\frac1n}}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\sin x}{\tan x+1}dx $$
by using the DCT. Now under $\tan(\frac x2)\to x$, one has
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\sin x}{\tan x+1}dx=2\int_0^1\frac{(2x+1)(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)(x^2-2x-1)}dx$$
which can be handled by partial fractions easily.