# Prove that $\int_0^\infty\left(\arctan \frac1x\right)^2 \mathrm d x = \pi\ln 2$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, conjectures, experimental-mathematics

> Prove $$\int_0^\infty\left(\arctan \frac1x\right)^2 \mathrm d x = \pi\ln 2$$

Out of boredom, I decided to play with some integrals and Inverse Symbolic Calculator and accidentally found this to my surprise

$$\int_0^\infty\Big(\arctan \frac1x\Big)^2 \mathrm d x = \pi\ln 2 \quad (\text{conjectural}) \,\,\, {\tag{1}} $$

Here is [Wolfram Alpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate%5BArcTan%5BE%5E-y%5D%5E2%20E%5Ey,%7By,-100,100%7D,WorkingPrecision-%3E60%5D%2F(%5C%5BPi%5D%20Log%5B2%5D)) which shows (1) to be true to 50 digits. Is (1) true and how to prove it?

I can calculate

$$\int_0^\infty\arctan \frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm d x = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$$

easily by expanding $\arctan$ into Maclaurin series. But how to proceed with $\arctan^2$?

Comment: Here what you can try. Do integration by part. And you'll get something like this $something + \int arctan(\frac{1}{x})2x\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=something+\int arctan(\frac{1}{x})dln(1+x^2)$. Then do integration by part once more. I think you'll get a nice version.

Comment: If you take $x=\cot t$, Mathematica gives $\pi  \ln 2$ for the transformed integral.

Comment: The answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933377/closed-form-of-int-0-infty-left-frac-arctan-xx-rightndx/2939452#2939452) with $n:=2$ because of $\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\infty\left(\arctan\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 dx=  \int\limits_0^\infty\left(\frac{\arctan x}{x}\right)^2 dx$ .

Answer (score 18):

$$\int_0^\infty \arctan^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx\overset{\frac{1}{x}\to t}=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan^2 t}{t^2}dt\overset{IBP}=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan t}{t(1+t^2)}dt$$
$$\overset{t=\tan x}=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{x}{\tan x}dx\overset{IBP}=-2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\sin x)dx=\pi\ln 2$$
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690693/515527) for the last integral.

Comment: Thought about the same (+1) `^^`

Comment: I guess that I got the fast fingers, haha :D

Comment: Indeed. Also, right now I'm only on mobile from which it is inconvenient to write out an answer containing to much MathJax expressions; otherwise I surely would've beat you ;)

Comment: The limits don’t make sense to me.... If $1/x=t$, then for the lower limit $x\to0\implies t\to\infty$, and for the upper limit $x\to\infty\implies t\to0$, but the order is flipped. What happened there?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I used the minus sign to flip them. $x=\frac{1}{t}\Rightarrow dx=\color{red}- \frac{1}{t^2}{dt}$. And yes we have
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=-\int_b^a f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 15):

First the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x$ and then integration by parts yield
$$\int_0^\infty\arctan^2x^{-1}\,dx=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan x}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx$$
so it suffices to evaluate the integral on the right. Define the function
$$f(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan (ax)}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx$$
and differenciate with respecto to $a$ to obtain
$$f'(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)(a^2+x^2)}=
\frac\pi2\frac1{1+a}.$$
Thus
$$f(a)=\frac\pi2\log(1+a)+C$$
where the constant $C$ can be seen to be $0$ letting $a=0$. The result is now immediate letting $a=1$.

Comment: Not sure about last part, but alternatively we can write:$$\require{cancel} f'(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\cancel{1-a}}{\cancel{(1-a)}(1+a)}\Rightarrow f(a)=\frac{\pi}{2} \ln (1+a)+C$$
Now for $a=0$ we get $C=0$ and it follows that $I=2f(1)=\pi \ln 2$

Comment: @Zacky Well.... yes, you're completely right, that's faster. I was relying to much on Mathematica :)

Answer (score 12):

Let
$$ I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty\left(\arctan \frac ax\right)\left(\arctan \frac bx\right) \mathrm d x. $$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial^2I(a,b)}{\partial a\partial b}&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\mathrm d x\\
&=&\frac{1}{a^2-b^2}\int_0^\infty \bigg(\frac{a^2}{x^2+a^2}-\frac{b^2}{x^2+b^2}\bigg)\mathrm d x\\
&=&\frac{1}{a^2-b^2}\frac\pi2(a-b)\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{a+b}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ I(1,1)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{a+b}\mathrm d a\mathrm d b=\frac\pi2\int_0^1(\ln(b+1)-\ln b)\mathrm d b=\pi\ln2.$$

Comment: That is a very nice "generalised" approach.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\arctan \frac{1}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan x$ (simply draw a triangle with side $1$ and $x$ and consider the two angles). We then obtain $$I = \int_0^\infty \left( \arctan \frac{1}{x} \right)^2 \mathrm d x = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan x \right)^2 \mathrm d x,$$
and we make the substitution $x = \tan u$ to obtain $$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec^2 u \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - u \right)^2 \mathrm d u = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec^2 u \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - u \right)^2 \mathrm d u$$ and again making a substitution $v = \frac{\pi}{2} - u$ gives
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{v^2}{\sin^2(v)} \mathrm d v$$
which is in fact evaluatable (although requires the polylogarithm function to express):
$$\int \frac{v^2}{\sin^2(v)} \mathrm d v = -i(v^2 + \mathrm{Li}_2(e^{2iv}))-v^2 \cot(v) + 2v \ln(1-2e^{iv}) + c,$$ upon which evaluating at both bounds gives $\pi \ln (2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x=\cot t$, the required integral becomes $$I=\int t^2 \csc^2 t~ dt= -t^2 \cot t-\int 2 t \cot t~ dt= -t^2 \cot t-2t \ln \sin t+ \int  2 \ln \sin t ~ dt. $$ Taking limits from $t=\pi/2$ to $x=0$ and using the well known integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \sin t ~dt=-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2,$$ we get the required result.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $y=\arctan \frac{1}{x} $ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I=& \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} y^2 \csc ^2 y d y \\
&=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} y^2 d(\cot y) \\
&=-\left[y^2 \cot y\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2} } y \cot yd y \\
&=2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} y d(\ln (\sin y))\\&= 2[y \ln (\sin y)]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin y) d y\\&=\pi \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you may use the fact that $\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac\pi2$ when $x>0$. We can also "fold up" the integral at $x=1$ to write

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\infty \arctan^2\left(\frac1x\right) \, dx \\[1ex]
&= \left\{\int_0^1 + \int_1^\infty\right\} \left(\frac\pi2 - \arctan(x)\right)^2 \, dx \\[1ex]
&= \int_0^1 \left(\frac\pi2 - \arctan(x)\right)^2 \, dx + \int_0^1 \left(\frac\pi2 - \arctan\left(\frac1x\right)\right)^2 \, \frac{dx}{x^2} \\[1ex]
&= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{\pi^2}4 - \pi \arctan(x) + \arctan^2(x) + \frac{\arctan^2(x)}{x^2}\right) \, dx \\[1ex]
&= \frac\pi2 \log(2) + \int_0^1 \left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right) \arctan^2(x) \, dx
\end{align*}$$

and from [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984725/closed-form-of-int-01-left-frac-arctan-xx-rightn-dx?rq=1) and [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713971/integral-int-01-left-arctan-x-right2-dx) we find the remaining integral to make up the difference so $I=\pi\log(2)$.