# Computing $\int_0^1\frac{1-2x}{2x^2-2x+1}\ln(x)\text{Li}_2(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form, polylogarithm

Any idea how ot approach

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{1-2x}{2x^2-2x+1}\ln(x)\text{Li}_2(x)dx\ ?$$

I came across this integral while I was trying to find a different solution for $\Re\ \text{Li}_4(1+i)$ posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290798/a-conjectured-value-for-operatornamere-operatornameli-4-1-i).

here is how I came across it;

using [the identity](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2598361216927327&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)\text{Li}_2(x)}{1-ax}dx=\frac{\text{Li}_2^2(a)}{2a}+3\frac{\text{Li}_4(a)}{a}-2\zeta(2)\frac{\text{Li}_2(a)}{a}$$

multiply both sides by $\frac{a}{3}$ then replace $a$ by $1+i$ and consider the the real parts of both sides we have

$$\Re\ \text{Li}_4(1+i)=-\frac16\Re\ \text{Li}_2^2(1+i)+\frac23\zeta(2)\Re\ \text{Li}_2(1+i)+\frac13\Re \int_0^1\frac{(1+i)}{1-(1+i)x}\ln(x)\text{Li}_2(x)dx$$

For the integral, use $\Re\frac{1+i}{1-(1+i)x}=\frac{1-2x}{2x^2-2x+1}$ which gives $I$.

What I tried is subbing $1-2x=y$ which gives

$$I=\int_{-1}^1\frac{-y}{1+y^2}\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{2}\right)\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+y}{2}\right)dy=\int_{-1}^1 f(y)dy=\underbrace{\int_{-1}^0 f(y)dy}_{y\to\ -y}+\int_{0}^1 f(y)dy$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+y^2}\ln\left(\frac{1-y}{2}\right)\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-y}{2}\right)dy-\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+y^2}\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{2}\right)\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+y}{2}\right)dy$$

I think I made it more complicated. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: \begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{1-2x}{2x^2-2x+1}\ln(x)\text{Li}_2(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)\text{Li}_2(x)\left(\frac{1-i}{1-(1-i)x}+\frac{1+i}{1-(1+i)x}\right)\end{align} and the identity is true for $a$ complex not equal to $1$.

Comment: @FDP Cornel says the integral must be understood as a Cauchy principle value for a>1.

Comment: @FDP for the case a=0, we better use the limit as a approaches 0.

Comment: @FDP also note that for the case a>1 we need to consider the real part of the right hand side of the identity.

Comment: Shater: You're right but, anyway, for $a$ not real the formula holds

Comment: @FDP I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+y^2}\ln\left(\frac{1-y^2}{4}\right)\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-y}{2}\right)dy+\frac{7}{32} \zeta (3) \log (2)+\frac{ \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{8}-\frac{157 \pi ^4}{46080}-\frac{ 11\log ^4(2)}{48}+\frac{19}{384} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)$$
 Put $$y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$$
 $$\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+y^2}\ln\left(\frac{1-y^2}{4}\right)\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-y}{2}\right)dy=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx+2\int_0^1\frac{x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx$$
be continued
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx=3\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{\pi^4}{30}+\frac{21}8\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\ln^22$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx=\frac{C^2}{2}+\frac{15 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{16}-\frac{701 \pi ^4}{46080}+\frac{7}8\ln2\zeta(3)+\frac{5 \log ^4(2)}{128}-\frac{3}{64} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)$$

Comment: Combine the two integrals using the relation (3.4.5) of MHZ page 22

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx=3\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{\pi^4}{30}+\frac{21}8\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\ln^22$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+x^2}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx=\frac{C^2}{2}+\frac{15 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{16}-\frac{701 \pi ^4}{46080}+\frac{7}8\ln2\zeta(3)+\frac{5 \log ^4(2)}{128}-\frac{3}{64} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx=3\text{Li}_4(2)+\text{Li}_2(2)\log^22-3\text{Li}_3(2)\log2+6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{21}4\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\log^22+\frac{1}{4}\log^42-\frac{29\pi^4}{288}$$
I being known,I deduce
 $$\int_0^1\frac{x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\ dx=-\frac{1}{16}\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{21}{64}\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{41}{768} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)-\frac{1}{96}\log^42+\frac{1609\pi^4}{92160}-\frac{3}{2}\text{Li}_4(2)-\frac{1}{2}\text{Li}_2(2)\log^22+\frac{3}{2}\text{Li}_3(2)\log2$$
Sorry,i couldn't deduct this integral.
$$3\text{Li}_4(2)+\text{Li}_2(2)\log^22-3\text{Li}_3(2)\log2=-3\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{21}8\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{8}\log^42+\frac{\pi^4}{15}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$=\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+y^2}\ln\left(\frac{1-y}{2}\right)\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-y}{2}\right)dy=2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{133}{64}\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{37}{768} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)+\frac{77}{384}\log^42-\frac{3197\pi^4}{92160}-\frac{C^2}{2}-\frac{1}{8} \pi  C \log (2)+\frac{3}{2}\text{Li}_4(2)+\frac{1}{2}\text{Li}_2(2)\log^22-\frac{3}{2}\text{Li}_3(2)\log2$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+y^2}\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{2}\right)\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+y}{2}\right)dy=\frac{47}{16}\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{133}{64}\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{61}{768} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)+\frac{23}{96}\log^42-\frac{4367\pi^4}{92160}+\frac{1}{8} \pi  C \log (2)+\frac{3}{2}\text{Li}_4(2)+\frac{1}{2}\text{Li}_2(2)\log^22-\frac{3}{2}\text{Li}_3(2)\log2$$

Comment: Very impressive! I'm also working on similar integrals.

Comment: I'm not sure how does this answer the question. OP clearly wants an idea how to approach the integral, not some results that should be on the comments section. Given the length I can understand why you posted an answer, but why 4 answers and not just 1 for all 4 that could be comments?

Comment: @
I did the best I could, but in fact I made a mistake that I could not correct