# Two nice (challenging) binoharmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I've recently seen a nice binoharmonic series from Ali's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1736736000) (page 309), but that post, for some reason, vanished (**Update**: that post was undeleted and now it may be found here [Evaluating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^2 \cot x\ln(1-\sin x)\mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625939)).

It is an excellent addition to MSE, that is,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}} \frac{H_{2n}}{n^3}.$$
since finding elegant ways is not easy to do.

I would also add the following variant, which seems to be **a new one** (in case it is known, any reference will be highly appreciated),
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}} \frac{H_{2n}}{n^4}.$$
Can we find very elegant ways to go for these two series?

Lots of other variants we could consider, like
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}} \frac{H_{2n}^2}{n^2}.$$

More curious binoharmonic structures (only a few examples in the list of possible *items* alike, keeping the weight $\le5$),
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}} \frac{H_n H_{2n}}{n^2};$$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}} \frac{H_n H_{2n}}{n^3};$$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}} \frac{H_n H_{2n}}{(2n+1)^2};$$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}} \frac{H_n H_{2n}}{(2n+1)^3}.$$

Let me also make a little update (**February 03, 2023**):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}} \frac{H_n H_{2n}H_{4n}}{n^2};$$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}} \frac{H_n H_{2n}H_{4n}}{(2n+1)^2}.$$

**Update**: **Yes**, that's the answer to the question above concerning the first series, and we can get **brilliant proofs**, and a paper is under work, which will be available soon.

Comment: You did not ask a question.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Álvarez He did, see line 9 of the OP.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze, what is "a way to go"? (Line numbers do not mean anything here, btw)

Comment: I deleted it because I remember I saw a similar post that I posted here on MSE before. I tried to find now but couldn't find it. I'll undelete it now

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I like to philosophize, too.

Comment: @AliShadhar Ok. Did you ever try any of the other binoharmonic series?

Comment: No I have not but I think I can get the integral representations of these monster series and I think that's all I can do   . Such series are quite challenging

Comment: I found a way that's different than Ali's for $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{4^kH_{2k}}{k^3\binom{2k}{k}}$. I posted it in the updated link, might be elegant enough.